How to write Events to specific Task Scheduler EventLog with Powershell
I created a powershell script (AD-Mapping) which runs as scheduled task. Inside this script I want to check for different errors which I would like to write in the EventLog which is automatically created with the task visible inside the tab history.

I know, I can create my own event log with New-EventLog and Write-EvengLog. But how can I use the already existing one?
When I check the existing Event Logs with Get-EventLog * I can see my custom one but I can't find the EventLog from my Scheduled Task.
PS C:\Users\**** Get-EventLog *

  Max(K) Retain OverflowAction        Entries Log
  ------ ------ --------------        ------- ---
     512      7 OverwriteOlder              1 AD-Mapping Eventlog
  20’480      0 OverwriteAsNeeded      60’860 Application
  20’480      0 OverwriteAsNeeded           0 HardwareEvents
     512      7 OverwriteOlder                Internet Explorer
  20’480      0 OverwriteAsNeeded           0 Key Management Service
     128      0 OverwriteAsNeeded       1’336 OAlerts
                                              Security
  20’480      0 OverwriteAsNeeded      92’230 System
  15’360      0 OverwriteAsNeeded      13’103 Windows PowerShell

PS C:\Users\****> Get-EventLog Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational
Get-EventLog : The event log 'Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational' on computer '.' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-EventLog Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-EventLog], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetEventLogCommand

And I also can't find any way to write into this one. What's the difference between the EventLogs from Get-EventLog and the EventLog form the History in the Task Scheduler?
